# Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have added library spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar with org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean class to build path, but it still doesn`t work.

I`m new in Spring, help me, please.

Thanks.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation="         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.devcolibri.common.controller" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>
                /WEB-INF/pages/
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>
                .jsp
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}" p:packagesToScan="com.devcolibri.common" />
    <!--  Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}" p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}" p:user="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}" p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100" p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />
    <!--  Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans>
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
 <context:annotation-config />

 <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
  For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.devcolibri.common.controller" />

 <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
 Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
 <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

hivernate-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      ">

 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.crawler.dao.model.ScrapingProperties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

spring.properties

```
# database properties
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/new_db
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=111111

#hibernate properties
hibernate.config=/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Using

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
...
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Eclipse log

```
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 9 2015 08:36:58 UTC
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.65.0
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Jre_1.8.0_65
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\PC\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Tomcat 7.0
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\PC\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 7.0
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\PC\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Jre_1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Jre_1.8.0_65/bin/client;C:/Jre_1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Jre_1.8.0_65/lib/i386;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Projects\Bpl;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;;C:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32;;.
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 515 ms
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
may 10, 2016 8:58:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commodityService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 33 more

may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SpringMVC] startup failed due to previous errors
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
may 10, 2016 8:58:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1456 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the below in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and hibernate-context.xml and see if it makes any difference. As per the link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadspringorm311RELEASEjar.htm the bean class is in a different folder.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AbstractSessionFactoryBean
```

to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after changing the class in both xml`s there is the same error for new bean class "org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean] "

Comment: Try Removing it from mvc dispatcher file and see it if makes any diff

Comment: i dont think you need it twice once in hibernate config file. i have mentioned it once only in hibernate config

Comment: Yep, after you mentioned that sessionFactory is declared two times, I removed it from mvc-dispatcher.xml and get the same error. Completely confused with it. Thanks!

Comment: please post your pom.xml

Comment: I tried to compile it without Maven, so I dont have it.

Comment: what version of hibernate you are using? just want to make sure

Comment: Third, hibernate-3.0.1.jar.

Comment: Here is it, next comment. Thanks!

Comment: if you removed it from th mvc file why is it still failing at the same line. if you had removed if should not have given you that error as it was removed, makes sense?

Comment: @Serg83 you probably using the wrong jar - try downloading the jar from this site - this would be the one for  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.0.1.RELEASE  you mentioned hibernate-3.0.1.jar but the name of this jar is spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @ElenaChubukina Yes, I`m using orm.hibernate-3.0.1.jar because there is defined SessionFactory. That string of code makes using orm.hibernate-3.0.1.jar neccessary.  Am I wrong? Thanks!  @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Comment: @Serg83  and if you delete orm.hibernate-3.0.1.jar and leave only spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar - do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, hibernate-3.0.1.jar, without orm, of course. If I delete it, it can`t be compile because of org.hibernate.Query and org.hibernate.Session cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Serg83  and if you try to use org.hibernate.SessionFactory instead of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean ? It looks like the problem might be in your dependencies

Comment: @ElenaChubukina Thanks a lot for your help! It works! Best regards!

Comment: @Serg83 I am really glad I could be of help! Would you mind if I post it as an answer and you accept it?

Comment: @Serg83 I posted it as a separate answer - so mark it as a correct pls. And indeed think about using some tool like maven - you would see that it is easier to trace the dependencies problems with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commodityService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hibernate-3.0.1.jar, try to use org.hibernate.SessionFactory instead of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean. 
And think about using Maven or some other tool - it would be much easier to trace dependencies problems in such case.